# Modify Applets to Support 2nd Environment

Tags: java, applet

I think I will be as vague as anyone can be - and please understand that is because of my limited knowledge. Simply put, I do not even know what to share to make my problem clearer at this moment.

Let me describe what I am facing and what needs to be done as follows:

Firstly there was edocs services running in uat environment. Now, there is a need for uat2 environment. So I was tasked to modify the build file to generate two wars - edocs. and edocs2.war (for uat and uat2 respectively). I was able to generate the two wars from the same build file. Now, I also need to "modify the applets to support uat2". I believe that I need to modify the current paths (?) in applets so that they would run in respective environment (uat and uat2), but I just do not understand how to modify the codes related to applets to support the two environments.

I hope I was able to describe my problem. HELP!!

Comment: Hm, what do you mean exactly by environment? Running in another servlet server (e.g. Tomcat)? Or running in the same servlet container but a different context? Are your applets part of the WAR file? Is it an internal application only accessible inside the local intranet or for the internet? Are the applets signed? It is impossible to help you with so little information. The one who has assigned you the task should instruct you correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed the instructions have been very vague till now. However, let me try to add more clarifications - there were 4 environments to begin with: DEV, QAT, UAT and PROD. Now UAT is going to be broken down into UAT and UAT2. Now I have the codes for UAT, I need to "modify" applets for UAT2 (one code-two environments). Also, the applets are signed, and the application will be used internally in the organization. And, the applets are not part of the WAR files (I think so, because I didn't run into any applets while modifying the build file). Thanks.